# Push Notification Using Amazon SNS (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am trying to implement push notification using Amazon SNS in Node. I have created a topic and published a message using below code

**Create Topic**

```
var createTopicPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).createTopic({Name: "TOPIC_NAME"}).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
createTopicPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("Topic ARN is " + data.TopicArn);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
```

I got a `TopicArn` something like this `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:TOPIC_NAME`

**Publish**

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set region
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create publish parameters
var params = {
  Message: 'You Got Message!! Hello....', /* required */
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:TOPIC_NAME'
};

// Create promise and SNS service object
var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
publishTextPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}");
    console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
```

Now the message have been published now I need to see this on my mobile. So I used subscribe code like this

```
    var params = {
      Protocol: 'application', /* required */
      TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:TOPIC_NAME', /* required */
      Endpoint: 'MOBILE_ENDPOINT_ARN'
    };

    // Create promise and SNS service object
    var subscribePromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31' }).subscribe(params).promise();

    req;
    res;
    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    subscribePromise.then(
      function (data) {
        console.log("Subscription ARN is " + data.SubscriptionArn);
      }).catch(
        function (err) {
          console.error(err, err.stack);
        });
  }
```

My question is what is `Endpoint` in Subscribe params. Where should I get this? and So far Am I right ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint here is the ARN of your mobile application that you need to register with AWS. Here is the snippet from the official documentation

> For Amazon SNS to send notification messages to mobile endpoints,
>   whether it is direct or with subscriptions to a topic, you first need
>   to register the app with AWS.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-register.html

Comment: I can't do without GCM or APNS ?